# Oracle connection get closed

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am facing a very strange behavior. My java application create a connection (java.sql.Connection) against an Oracle db, successfully. When I try to execute a
statement, I got a:

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Connection closed

exception. This is how the application creates the connection (as in the old times):

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "usr", "pwd");
```

connection is never closed (almost intentionally) since before the program exits (in a finally block, as teacher told us). 
If I use this method to obtain a connection,

```
protected Connection getConn() throws Exception {
if(conn == null || conn.isClosed()) {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "usr", "pwd");
}
return conn;
}
```

everything works fine. As I get the connection, the method verify it's close and recreate a new one. I can't figure out what's happen. Why the connection close? TIA.

Francesco

Comment: Can you post the more code. Need to know the scope of the Connection conn.

Comment: It's an old style java application, not an enterprise one. `Connection conn` is private attribute of the superclass of my `main(String[] args)` class, which get `conn` by the superclass's getter method (the `getConn` one). Sorry I can't post the code.

Comment: Can you post full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Can you please post some more code , may be there is some other problem.

Comment: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Connessione chiusa at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3560) at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3461) ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code as written is a good idea.  I'd do something more like this:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * util.DatabaseUtils
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Aug 17, 2010
 * Time: 7:58:02 PM
 */
public class DatabaseUtils {
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:database";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "password";
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "pgsuper";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pgsuper";
*/
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "party";
*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String driver = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        String url = ((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : DEFAULT_URL);
        String username = ((args.length > 2) ? args[2] : DEFAULT_USERNAME);
        String password = ((args.length > 3) ? args[3] : DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = createConnection(driver, url, username, password);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSON ORDER BY LAST_NAME";
            System.out.println("before insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO PERSON(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            List parameters = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar");
            int numRowsUpdated = update(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsUpdated);
            System.out.println("after insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(connection);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("wall time: " + (endTime - begTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(driver);
        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0)) {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } else {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            close(rs);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            results = map(rs);
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static int update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        int numRowsUpdated = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            numRowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(ps);
        }
        return numRowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Usefull! Thank you. But the problem is the connection. I got a new `Connection` object, as soon as I use it to create a statement, i got the exception I wrote about 'cause the connection is close. Oracle listener log does report nothing. Thanks again for the code.

Comment: Try it my way.  I'll bet your problem goes away.  Throw your code away, replace it with mine, and see how it goes.